# 2010 Access report, partial match from inputted search criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a report that uses the following SQL query:

```
SELECT AccountPerformanceAllHistory.AccountNumber, 
AccountMaster.AccountName AS Name, AccountCurrentModel.Model,    
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.MarketValue, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.Cash, ModelDetailAllHistory.Risk, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.QTD, AccountPerformanceAllHistory.YTD, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.[1Yr], AccountPerformanceAllHistory.[3Yr], 
AccountMaster.AccountAdvisor AS Advisor, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.PerformanceDate, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.Ticker
FROM ModelDetailAllHistory INNER JOIN ((AccountMaster INNER JOIN 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory ON AccountMaster.[AccountNumber] = 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.[AccountNumber]) INNER JOIN 
AccountCurrentModel ON AccountMaster.[AccountNumber] = AccountCurrentModel. 
[AccountNumber]) ON ModelDetailAllHistory.[ModelName] = 
AccountCurrentModel.Model
GROUP BY AccountPerformanceAllHistory.AccountNumber, 
AccountMaster.AccountName, AccountCurrentModel.Model, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.MarketValue, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.Cash, ModelDetailAllHistory.Risk, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.QTD, AccountPerformanceAllHistory.YTD, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.[1Yr], AccountPerformanceAllHistory.[3Yr], 
AccountMaster.AccountAdvisor, AccountPerformanceAllHistory.PerformanceDate, 
AccountPerformanceAllHistory.Ticker
ORDER BY ModelDetailAllHistory.Risk, AccountPerformanceAllHistory.[1Yr] 
DESC;
```

The report is run from a button-click:

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()

Dim StrWhichMonth As String
Dim StrWhichClient As String
Dim CYear, CMonth As Variant
Dim StrSearch As String

StrWhichMonth = InputBox("Enter YYMM you want to report:")
CYear = "20" & Mid(StrWhichMonth, 1, 2)
CMonth = Mid(StrWhichMonth, 3, 2)
StrWhichMonth = DateSerial(CYear, CMonth + 1, 0)

StrWhichClient = InputBox("Enter Client name ('*' for all):")

StrSearch = "AccountPerformanceAllHistory.PerformanceDate = #" & StrWhichMonth _
    & "# AND AccountPerformanceAllHistory.Ticker = " & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & "" _
    & " AND AccountMaster.AccountName Like " & Chr(34) & StrWhichClient & Chr(34)

StrWhichMonth = "AccountPerformanceAllHistory.PerformanceDate = #" & StrWhichMonth _
    & "# AND AccountPerformanceAllHistory.Ticker = " & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & ""
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'    DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTAccountPerformanceAllHistorySummary", acViewReport, , StrWhichMonth
DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTAccountPerformanceAllHistorySummary", acViewReport, , StrSearch
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

As you might can tell, I added the search for AccountName in the button click code.  The old code works fine.

The new code, with the StrSearch string does not work.  When the query is run, it prompts for "AccountMaster.AccountName" after the two InputBox prompts. I know this means something is wrong with the StrSearch, but I don't know what is wrong.  I've searched around the web, but could not find a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print StrSearch , StrWhichMonth` and see what you are passing as a string. I suspect your getting a dd/mm/yyyy date and you preferably need it formatted as #yyyy/mm/dd# to avoid any US / UK ambiguity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field list in your source query includes this one ...

```
AccountMaster.AccountName AS Name
```

Since you aliased the field, the query result set does not include a field named `AccountMaster.AccountName`, so Access assumes it must be a parameter and asks you to supply a value for it. Use the alias instead instead of the original field name.

Change this ...

```
& " AND AccountMaster.AccountName Like " & Chr(34) & StrWhichClient & Chr(34)
```

to this ...

```
& " AND [Name] Like " & Chr(34) & StrWhichClient & Chr(34)
```